# How to verify JWT token is manipulated by user or not in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jwt

How to verify JWT token is manipulated by user or not in PHP Codeigniter 4?

I am applying JWT authentication. But How to verify the token is manipulated or not.
When User manipulating the token its showing error that " Wrong number of segments
in" jwt.php

Comment: Why not use a signed token?

Answer (score 0):

Each client needs to request a token from the back to verify their requests at least once.

Tokens are created on the server side with a secret key, this key should never be shared.

With this key the token is signed, and the client can decode it and access the token but not modify it

Source: https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/